# Can I say "got up" or "waked up"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Are the following sentences correct?

> *He just got up.* -- Can I say this, informally?
>   *He just waked up.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can say either sentence, but waked is used far less often than **woke**.

He just **woke** up.

wake (base/infinitive)
**woke** (simple past)
woken (past participle)

The two sentences have almost the same meaning, and we often use them interchangeably.
There is a slight distinction: "He just woke up" tells us that the person is now awake. "He just got up" tells us that the person is now awake and implies that the person also got out of bed.

Comment: Now... retracted! :)

Comment: ```Waked up``` is a very unusual phrase to use these days and was never very popular. A quick check on the Google Ngram server gives a nice graph. Essentially just stick with wake, woke and woken. http://bit.ly/1IQFXHN

Answer (score 1):

It's fine!

> He just got up = He just waked up

Both mean informally that he's not sleeping now. He just finished his sleep.

However, it's worth knowing that '[wake up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wake-up_1)' and '[get up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+up)' mean many things other than the context of 'sleeping'. And I consider that you are talking about his state of 'sleeping'.

Note that ['woke up' is way more common than 'waked up'.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=woke%20up%2C%20waked%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwoke%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaked%20up%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Do you have a source that states the past tense of "wake" is "waked"? I can only find the irregular verb "woke".

Comment: @Stephie I did not bother to search it! I *know* that! :)

Comment: @Stephie okay, for you - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wake

Comment: @Stephie Maulik V is correct. I had to [check](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/wake.html) it myself because I'm so used to using woke.

Comment: Thanks. I just remember endless drills back in school: "wake - woke - woken"....

Comment: @Stephie True...I am being scolded so many times using 'waked' just because it's very less common. But it has become a habit of mine! Cannot help it :(

Comment: @MaulikV Now you got me curious: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221905/past-tense-of-wake-is-there-a-difference-between-waken-and-woke - let's see what happens. (I can find the two origins in todays German, my mother tongue, too!)

Comment: @Stephie I can answer that! 'waked up' is valid but *not much in practice* these days! haha! :)

Answer (score -1):

My answers honestly is that woke up is the best and some times you could say got up but of course you can't say than with someone you can use it in a diary that was an example 
But it's not common saying waked it's not from proper English